# Why have new inner tie rods made car less fun to drive?

Tags: driving, tie-rod

Car is civic vti 99.  I have just replaced one steering rack gaiter and both front inner tie rods after the one tie rod was found to be 'loose' while doing the gaiter replacement.

Since replacing tie rods the car doesn't seem to be feel as raw as before, I cannot feel the road , it doesn't seem as fast as before and when taking turns at speed it doesn't seem to skid like before.
Now the car feels soft, more sturdy and stable, insulated from the road and I have to pick up speed(previously I didn't) to feel like I am going fast. It also doesn't skid like before and feels much tighter around corners.

Basically with the loose tie rods it felt way more raw and cooler to drive, now it feels a lot more soft and stable.  Now is probably how its designed to\meant to drive.  However it leaves me wondering, why is it that loose tie rods would cause a car to seem/go faster(even if an illusion), feel the road more, and be more likely to skid around turns?  Personally I'd rather have it like it was before.

edit:  you guys are saying it's the alignment(which I did have to get done) however for many months prior it needed no alignment as it was straight and was far more enjoyable to drive than now so wouldn't this suggest the tie rods rather than an alignment makig the difference, unless i bought it aligned differently like someone suggested.

Comment: The maintenance has made the car **safer** for the rest of us...

Comment: Alignment is more than just tracking, caster, camber and kpi...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about the alignment. Typically a car's alignment is set up for stability compromised for tire wear. The car will have a little negative camber on all wheels, moderate caster, slight toe in on the back wheels, and slight toe out in the front for front wheel drive cars. Stability is nice and makes people feel safe and no one wants to replace tires every 5ooo miles.

Race cars tend to have more camber, much more toe in on the back wheels, less camber (sometimes), and much more toe out in the front. Specifically, this toe out makes the car feel unstable or loose. The car wants to turn a lot with just a little flick of the steering wheel. This setup is hell on tires but for a race car it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you had an alignment since changing the tie rod.  The alignment spec may be a little different than it was before.  Toe in is more stable than toe out.  This stability may make you feel slower.